# Slurm gpu-job on multiple gpu-nodes

Tags: configuration, gpu, nodes, slurm

I have a partition with two nodes and for each node I have made available 1 nvidia gpu + 8 cpu. Running a python job with one gpu is working:

```
sbatch --partition=gpu --gres=gpu:1 --mem-per-gpu=20G --cpus-per-gpu=8
```

but it doesn't run with 2 gpu, one per node

```
sbatch --partition=gpu --nodes=2 --gres=gpu:1 --mem-per-gpu=20G --cpus-per-gpu=8
```

Do I need to change any setup code/slurm/gres or install extra packages to fix this?

Thanks for the help!